# Not able to run fargate task from lambda when lambda is in a vpc

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

So the problem is that lambda needs to be able to read from a db which is in a vpc and start a ecs fargate task. But if the lambda is in a vpc then it does not start the task itself rather the lambda times out.

```
import json
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ecs')


cluster_name = 'as-dev'
task_name = 'as-dev:2'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    try:
        response = client.run_task(
            cluster=cluster_name,
            launchType = 'FARGATE',
            taskDefinition=task_name,
            count = 1,
            platformVersion='LATEST',
            networkConfiguration={
                'awsvpcConfiguration': {
                    'subnets': [
                        'subnet-12345ab12345'
                    ],
                    'securityGroups': [
                        'sg-123451234sasdqwe'
                    ],
                    'assignPublicIp': 'ENABLED'
                }
            }
            )
        print(response)
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
        }
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': str(e)
        }
```

(Configurations changed for obvious reasons)

The code works fine if run as a simple python program on ec2. Only when the vpc is added to the lambda does it stop working and times out.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly is happening? Any errors, timeouts?

Comment: it times out, Sorry have edited the question and added the same.

Comment: Still working on it. Using the ecs quickstart helps create the vpc subnets etc, then opening an ecs endpoint allows the lambda to hit ecs. But the same does not happen for a pre-existing vpc isn't working still, am trying to reverse engineer to see why. but you're right that it's a networking issue on the lambda's side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a lambda function in a VPC, has **no internet access**. A popular way to enable the access is through the use of NAT gateway and placing your lambda in a **private subnet** as explained in:

- [How do I give internet access to a Lambda function that's connected to an Amazon VPC?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/)

Alternative is to use [VPC interface endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpce-interface.html) for ECS. Once you set them up properly, you don't need to use internet. Instead your function will access ECS using the endpoint privately.

Comment: This answer works, just that it does not work with the default vpc created by aws, works with another vpc which could be your applications vpc(but not default), just have a private subnet and open an ecs endpoint in the same vpc/subnet. Just attaching this to lambda worked.